# BuddyPress Wiki Component action on init not called

Tags: php, wordpress, wiki, buddypress

I'm not really fit in wordpress but a friend of mine asked me to fix a problem in his wordpress installation. He is using Buddypress and the problem is in the wiki component. It is not possible to create new articles in the wiki. I have looked into the code and found the code which should create the db entry.

```
add_action( 'init', 'bp_wiki_group_page_create' );
```

I think this should mean the function add_action( 'init', 'bp_wiki_group_page_create' ); should be called after all the init stuff is loaded.

But when I put some debug stuff in this function it is never displayed. So I think something goes wrong with the hook.
When I add my own method to the init action it is displayed.

Can you give me some tips where I can look for the problem? I can give more information if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is found at https://buddypress.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/4195. In short, the BuddyPress Wiki Component should be using the bp_include action instead of bp_init, which is too late.

Reference: http://codex.buddypress.org/plugin-development/checking-buddypress-is-active/